# Writing a custom desktop notification for Mac OS X, like the Volume pop up

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Is there an API for creating desktop notifications for OS X, like the ones used when you change the system volume, press play, build something in XCode 4, etc? Something like this:

[image: OS X volume pop-up]

Would something like this have to be made manually, using headless windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Growl framework. It's the easiest way.[Link](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php).
Or you can do it using custom, borderless windows.
PS. If you want to create your own notification app(like growl) you can use growl's source code as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've heard of Growl but I'm more interested in using built-in APIs to achieve this, so end users won't need Growl installed. I don't mind going the custom window route, I just thought I'd check to see if it was already possible out of the box.

Comment: You are welcome. Anyway Growl's source code is a nice example. Good luck!

Comment: Requiring users to have/use growl _is_ just annoying.

Comment: Yup. But it's not a big deal to make your own notifications in case a user don't have growl.